# In asp.net webservices (asmx), is the CacheDuration applied when called from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

When I set `CacheDuration` over a method in asmx service it gets applied correctly.
Now if I called this method from another method in the same website or even from the same service, does this duration get applied too?

Comment: @devRicher if I found an answer I wouldn't have done it :)

Comment: When you call the method which has cache duration from a method in the same web service, no the cache will not be applied. It will work like any other normal method.

Comment: When you call the method from the same web site, since you use it without add web reference and use it like a normal method, no, the cache will not be applied.

Comment: I posted a simple example demonstrating the case. It's not a formal test method but it shows what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the method which has cache duration:

- Call from the same web site like a normal method → Calls without cache
- Call from the same service like a normal method →  Calls without cache
- Call as a web service method (using service proxy) → Calls with cache

The cache applies just when the call goes through ASP.NET pipeline. But if you call the method like a normal method, it doesn't use cache. In fact `WebMethod` attribute doesn't have any impact on calls when the call is a normal method call.

**Example**

I suppose you are looking for a simple test scenario, so you can create such web service to test:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(CacheDuration=10)]
    public string GetDate1()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetDate2()
    {
        return this.GetDate1();
    }
}
```

**1)** To test calling method from the same project, in an aspx page you can write such code in a button click and run it 3-4 times to see the result:

```
var svc = new WebService1();
this.Label1.Text = string.Format("{0} | {1}", svc.GetDate1(), svc.GetDate2());
```

In all executions you will see the time without any cache and you can see no difference between calling from the same site and calling from the same service.

**2)** Also to test calling as web service method, add web reference to a windows forms project for example, in a button click write:

```
var svc = new localhost.WebService1();
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} | {1}", svc.GetDate1(), svc.GetDate2()));
```

Then you can see the `svc.GetDate1()` shows cached data and `svc.GetDate2()` shows current time while it uses `svc.GetDate1()` internally. So calling as a web service uses cache, but calling from the same web service doesn't use cache.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! I should be able to award bounty in 14 hours they say :)